# How to Enable and Disable Submit Button Using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code i want to have disable submit button after page load and enabled button when im typing in the textbox. pls help thanks

```
<div class="container" id="frmtoken">
    <form method=POST action="authorize.php">   
        <div class="featured-desc-left">
            <p>Enter token and wait to be connected.</p>
            <p><strong>note: Only one device per token is allowed</strong></p>
        </div>

        <div class="two columns featured-desc-left">
            <p><input type="text" name="token"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="featured-desc-left">
            <p>
                <input name="tconnect" type="submit" value="Connect" 
                   onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending...';"/>
            </p>
        </div>              
    </form>                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled","disabled");
});

$("input[type=text]").on("keydown",function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Bearing in mind this will apply to all `submit` inputs on the page when any `text` inputs on the page are typed in so you probably should assign classes/ids.

Comment: thanks for your help. im new to this but ill try know what u mean to say. thanks